# Invoking gcc compiler from php in windows

Tags: php, c, gcc

I am having problem in running c program using gcc from php script.Below is my code.

```
$command = "gcc -o C:\wamp\www\exe\ex main.c";
  exec($command);

 $command = "C:\wamp\www\exe\e > C:\wamp\www\exe\out.txt";
 exec($command);
```

In command prompt it works fine.But I dont get any output in out.txt if I run from php.I use wamp server 2.5.
I think that second command runs before first command.Is there any way to make sure that the commands are run sequentially one after another through some if condition?